# haciendo una aplicación de productos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para cargar productos con **bootstrap** y **jquery**, ya hice la función para que cargue la información de los inputs dentro de un `.append`, lo que pasa es que al momento de cargar los datos se me van acumulando de manera repetitiva y me  desarman la estructura.

¿Alguno sabe como podría solucionar este problema y se carguen los productos de manera separada como en la foto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el código para se entienda mejor:

```js
function suma(){
 var especie;
 var cantidad;
 var precio;
 var total;
 especie = document.getElementById('especie').value;
 cantidad = document.getElementById('cant').value;
 precio = document.getElementById('compra').value;
 total = cantidad*precio;
   document.getElementById('subtotal').value = total;

   if(total > 0){

   
   $(".parrafo").innerHTML ="<p>Su cartera contiene los siguientes elementos:</p>";

   $(".cuadro").append(
    "<p class='col'>Especie</p><p class='col'>Cantidad</p><p class='col'>Precio($)</p><p class='col'>Total($)</p><p class='col'>Acción</p>")



   $(".cuadro2").append(
    "<p class='col'>"+especie+"</p><p class='col'>"+cantidad+"</p><p class='col'>"+precio+"</p><p class='col'>"+total+"</p><input type='button' class='btn btn-danger' value='-' onclick='borrar()' >")
   




   }
    
   };

function borrar(){
  $("p").remove("");
  $(".cuadro2").remove("input")
};
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}


.container{
 height: 400px;
 width: auto;
 
}

.ct1{
 padding: 0 20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bold;
 
}

.ct2{
 
}

.cuadro{
 margin-top: 50px;
 background-color: blue;
 color: white;
}

.cuadro2{
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Movizen Bootstrap</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="container bg-primary">
    <div class="row text-white ct1">
      <div class="col">Especie</div>
      <div class="col">Cantidad</div>
      <div class="col">Precio($)</div>
      <div class="col">Total($)</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row ct2">
     <input class="col" type="text" id="especie" placeholder="Especie">
     <input class="col"type="text" id="cant" placeholder="Cantidad">
     <input class="col" type="text" id="compra" placeholder="Precio compra">
     <input class="col" type="text" id="subtotal" placeholder="Total" disabled>
     <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" placeholder="Total" onclick="suma()" id="sum" value="+" />
    </div>
    <p class="parrafo"></p>
    <div class="row cuadro">
     
    </div>

    <div class="row cuadro2">
 </div>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te muestro el codigo corregido para hacer lo que pides, en el hay unos pequeños comentarios explicando el por qué

```js
function suma(){
  var especie;
  var cantidad;
  var precio;
  var total;
  especie = document.getElementById('especie').value;
  cantidad = document.getElementById('cant').value;
  precio = document.getElementById('compra').value;
  total = cantidad*precio;
  document.getElementById('subtotal').value = total;

  if(total > 0){
  
   // Las lineas encargadas de añadir texto al encabezado de la tabla han sido movidas al html, ya que solamentes necesario mostrarlas. Antes se estaban cargando una y otra vez, cosa que no era necesaria y rompia la estructura
    
    // Añadiendo numeros a la clase "col" podemos definir el numero de columnas que ocura, al sumar estas 12, ocuparan una linea entera

    $(".cuadro2").append(`
      <p class='col-3'>${especie}</p>
      <p class='col-2'>${cantidad}</p>
      <p class='col-2'>${precio}</p>
      <p class='col-3'>${total}</p>
      <p class="col-2"><input type='button' class='btn btn-danger' value='-' onclick='borrar()' ></p>
  `)

  }
  
  // Muestro u oculto el encabezado de la tabla dependiende de si esta vacia o no

  if ($('.cuadro2').children().length) {

    $(".parrafo").show()

    $(".cuadro").show()


  } else {

    $(".parrafo").hide()

    $(".cuadro").hide()

  }

};

function borrar(){
  $("p").remove("");
  $(".cuadro2").remove("input")
};
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}


.container{
  height: 400px;
  width: auto;

}

.ct1{
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;

}

.ct2{

}

.cuadro{
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.cuadro2{
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Movizen Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container bg-primary">

      <div class="row text-white ct1">
        <div class="col">Especie</div>
        <div class="col">Cantidad</div>
        <div class="col">Precio($)</div>
        <div class="col">Total($)</div>
      </div>

      <div class="row ct2">
        <input class="col" type="text" id="especie" placeholder="Especie">
        <input class="col"type="text" id="cant" placeholder="Cantidad">
        <input class="col" type="text" id="compra" placeholder="Precio compra">
        <input class="col" type="text" id="subtotal" placeholder="Total" disabled>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" placeholder="Total" onclick="suma()" id="sum" value="+" />
      </div>

      <p class="parrafo" style="display: none;">Su cartera contiene los siguientes elementos:</p>

      <div class="row cuadro" style="display: none;">
        <p class='col-3'>Especie</p>
        <p class='col-2'>Cantidad</p>
        <p class='col-2'>Precio($)</p>
        <p class='col-3'>Total($)</p>
        <p class='col-2'>Acción</p>
      </div>

      <div class="cuadro2 row"></div>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```